# parsing for PHOAS expressions

Tags: haskell

I think I understand PHOAS (parametric higher-order abstract syntax), 
and I see how we can pretty-print an expression (cf. http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/1mo59h/phoas_for_free_by_edward_kmett/ccbxzoo).

But - I don't see how to build a parser for such expressions, e.g., that takes `"(lambda (a) a)"` and builds (the Haskell value corresponding to) `lam $ \ x -> x`. (And it should use Text.Parsec or similar.)

I can build a parser that produces lambda terms with de-Bruijn indexing but what would it help?

Comment: Pass an environment of bindings from variables to terms, and turn variable parsing into a lookup operation. This can also be done as an AST transformation, I'd suggest this. Parse to something not PHOAS, then transform the parse tree into PHOAS.

Comment: OK, thanks for the working code in the answers. I was hoping to avoid this intermediate tree, for all the reasons that speak for PHOAS. E.g., the parser could check that the expression is closed (has no free variables), but in the intermediate AST, this information seems to be lost, and the conversion to PHOAS then looks non-total.

Comment: Either your parse or your transformation is partial, it's just a matter of picking your poison.

Comment: Well I want errors detected as early as possible, so - unbound variables should be flagged by the parser. This also gives nicer error messages (Parsec knows source pos, my AST doesn't).

Comment: I'd think twice about this. You're going to want to keep the positions around in any serious AST anyways. By that logic, our parsers should also do type checking and trivial optimizations. It's far easier to maintain a compiler were all the parser does is parse. And each intermediate language is in a seperate part of the compiler.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As jozefg says, you can easily convert between operations. I'll show how to convert between a named, a de-Bruijn, and a PHOAS representation of lambda terms. It's relatively easy to fuse that into the parser if you absolutely want to, but it's probably better to parse a named representation first and then convert.

Let's assume

```
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as M
```

and the following three representations of lambda terms:

#### `String`-based names

```
data LamN = VarN Name | AppN LamN LamN | AbsN Name LamN
  deriving (Eq, Show)

type Name = String
```

#### de-Bruijn indices

```
data LamB = VarB Int | AppB LamB LamB | AbsB LamB
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

#### PHOAS

```
data LamP a = VarP a | AppP (LamP a) (LamP a) | AbsP (a -> LamP a)
```

Now the conversions between LamP and the others (in both directions). Note that these are partial functions. If you're applying them to lambda terms that contain free variables, you're responsible for passing a suitable environment.

#### How to go from `LamN` to `LamP`

Takes an environment mapping names to
PHOAS variables. The environment can be empty for closed terms.

```
lamNtoP :: LamN -> Map Name a -> LamP a
lamNtoP (VarN n)     env = VarP (env M.! n)
lamNtoP (AppN e1 e2) env = AppP (lamNtoP e1 env) (lamNtoP e2 env)
lamNtoP (AbsN n e)   env = AbsP (\ x -> lamNtoP e (M.insert n x env))
```

#### How to go from `LamB` to `LamP`

Takes an environment that's a list of
PHOAS variables. Can be the empty list for closed terms.

```
lamBtoP :: LamB -> [a] -> LamP a
lamBtoP (VarB n)     env = VarP (env !! n)
lamBtoP (AppB e1 e2) env = AppP (lamBtoP e1 env) (lamBtoP e2 env)
lamBtoP (AbsB e)     env = AbsP (\ x -> lamBtoP e (x : env))
```

#### How to get from 'LamP' to 'LamN'

Requires potential free variables to
be instantiated to their names. Takes a supply of names for generating
names of binders. Should be instantiated to an infinite list of mutually
different names.

```
lamPtoN :: LamP Name -> [Name] -> LamN
lamPtoN (VarP n)         _sup  = VarN n
lamPtoN (AppP e1 e2)      sup  = AppN (lamPtoN e1 sup) (lamPtoN e2 sup)
lamPtoN (AbsP f)     (n : sup) = AbsN n (lamPtoN (f n) sup)
```

#### How to get from 'LamP' to 'LamB'

Requires potential free variables to
be instantiated to numbers. Takes an offset that indicates the number of
binders we're currently under. Should be instantiated to `0` for a closed
term.

```
lamPtoB :: LamP Int -> Int -> LamB
lamPtoB (VarP n)     off = VarB (off - n)
lamPtoB (AppP e1 e2) off = AppB (lamPtoB e1 off) (lamPtoB e2 off)
lamPtoB (AbsP f)     off = AbsB (lamPtoB (f (off + 1)) (off + 1))
```

#### An example

```
-- \ x y -> x (\ z -> z x y) y

sample :: LamN
sample = AbsN "x" (AbsN "y"
  (VarN "x" `AppN` (AbsN "z" (VarN "z" `AppN` VarN "x" `AppN` VarN "y"))
            `AppN` (VarN "y")))
```

Going to de-Bruijn via PHOAS:

```
ghci> lamPtoB (lamNtoP sample M.empty) 0
AbsB (AbsB (AppB (AppB (VarB 1) (AbsB (AppB (AppB (VarB 0) (VarB 2)) (VarB 1)))) (VarB 0)))
```

Going back to names via PHOAS:

```
ghci> lamPtoN (lamNtoP sample M.empty) [ "x" ++ show n | n <- [1..] ]
AbsN "x1" (AbsN "x2" (AppN (AppN (VarN "x1") (AbsN "x3" (AppN (AppN (VarN "x3") (VarN "x1")) (VarN "x2")))) (VarN "x2")))
```

Comment: I think it gets trickier when you change the PHOAS to support different types. E.g. change your AppP and AbsP to `(a -> b) -> a -> b`  and `(a -> b)`. I've managed to do this with Typeable, although not prettily.

Answer (score 6):

jozefg has the right answer in his comment.  Always parse to a simple abstract syntax tree, not some clever representation.  Then, after parsing, convert representations.  In this case, it is easy

```
data Named = NLam String Named | NVar String | NApp Named Named

convert :: (String -> a) -> Named -> Exp a a
convert f (NVar n) = var $ f n
convert f (NApp e1 e2) = app (convert f e1) (convert f e2)
convert f (NLam s e) = lam $ \a -> convert (nf a) e where
  nf a s' = if s' == s then a else f s'
```

you could of course use something other than a function `String -> a` as your map.  `Data.Map` for example would get rid of the linear time lookups.

One cool thing about PHOAS over other HOAS schemes is that you can easily "convert back"

```
addNames :: ExpF Int (State Int Named) -> State Int Named
addNames (App a b) = liftM2 NApp a b
addNames (Lam f)   = do
  i <- get
  put (i + 1)
  r <- f i
  return $ NLam ('x':show i) r

convert' :: Exp Int Int -> Named
convert' = fst 
  . flip runState 0
  . cata addNames 
  . liftM (return . NVar . ('x':) . show)
```

which even works as expected

```
λ: convert' $ convert undefined $ NLam "x" $ NApp (NVar "x") (NLam "y" (NVar "y"))
> NLam "x0" (NApp (NVar "x0") (NLam "x1" (NVar "x1")))
```

Answer (score 4):

I will again run with the theme of the other answers here and suggest that you parse as though you are just creating the naive representation with named variables. If you want to avoid the intermediate representation, you can kind of inline it into the parser without making it any harder to understand:

```
data Lam a = Var a | Lam a `App` Lam a | Lam (a -> Lam a)

type MkLam a = (String -> a) -> Lam a

var :: String -> MkLam a
var x = Var . ($ x)

app :: MkLam a -> MkLam a -> MkLam a
app = liftA2 App

lam :: String -> MkLam a -> MkLam a
lam v e env = Lam $ \x -> e $ \v' -> if v == v' then x else env v'
```

The idea is that instead of using the constructors of your intermediate representation in your parser, you use these functions directly. They have the same types that the constructors would have, so it's really just a drop-in replacement. It's also a bit shorter, since now we don't have to separately write out the ADT and interpreter.