# How to safely convert named syntax to PHOAS?

Tags: haskell

This question is essentially the same as [parsing for PHOAS expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415621/parsing-for-phoas-expressions), however I'm specifically looking for an answer that safely handles out of scope variables using the `Maybe` type (so without using Haskell's error mechanism).

Specifically I have these types:

```
type Name = Int

data Lam = Var Name | Lam Name Lam | App Lam Lam 

data LamP p = VarP p | LamP (p -> LamP p) | AppP (LamP p) (LamP p)
```

For simplicity I'm using integers as names.

Going from `LamP` to `Lam` is straightforward:

```
fromP :: (forall p. LamP p) -> Lam
fromP x0 = go 0 x0 where
  go _ (VarP n) = Var n
  go n (LamP f) = Lam n (go (n + 1) (f n))
  go n (AppP x y) = App (go n x) (go n y)
```

Here's my attempt at going in the other direction:

```
type Env p = Int -> Maybe p

emptyEnv :: Env p
emptyEnv = const Nothing

lookupEnv :: Env p -> Int -> Maybe p
lookupEnv = id

insertEnv :: Env p -> Int -> p -> Env p
insertEnv f n x m
  | n == m = Just x
  | otherwise = f m

toP :: Lam -> Maybe (LamP p)
toP x0 = go x0 emptyEnv where
  go :: Lam -> Env p -> Maybe (LamP p)
  go (Var n)   env = VarP <$> lookupEnv env n
  go (Lam n x) env =
    go x (insertEnv env n _) >>= \x' -> pure (LamP (\p -> _) -- <<< problem!
  go (App x y) env = AppP <$> go x env <*> go y env
```

It seems impossible to get the `p` from inside `LamP` to the `insertEnv` on the left of it.

However, I strongly believe the `Just/Nothing` result of the `go` computation should not depend on which `p` we insert into the environment. So I was thinking of putting in some kind of placeholder and filling it in later, but I can't work out how to do to that.

Or is it impossible to write this function?

Comment: I'll leave a link to [Unembedding Domain-Specific Languages](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/slindley/papers/unembedding.pdf), it only deals with HOAS but may be relevant (or interesting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a (partially incomplete) solution.

The idea is to pass through a GADT as an intermediate representation.

In FOAS, we use De Bruijn indices and Peano naturals to represent variables.

```
data Nat = O | S Nat

data Lam = Var Nat | Lam Lam | App Lam Lam
```

Now we use a GADT to represent a term which is guaranteed to have its free variables among `[0,n)`. These terms have a special `WeakC` syntax for explicit weakening, allowing us to consider a term whose free variables are in `[0,n)` as it they were in `[0,n+1)`.

```
-- Lam with free vars in [0,n)
data LamC (n :: Nat) where
   -- weakening: [0,n) is included in [0,n+1)
   WeakC :: LamC n -> LamC ('S n)
   -- the "last-bound" variable
   VarC :: LamC ('S n)
   LamC :: LamC ('S n) -> LamC n
   AppC :: LamC n -> LamC n -> LamC n

-- Example: (\x -> x (\y -> y x))
test :: LamC 'O
test = LamC (AppC (VarC {- x -})
            (LamC (AppC (VarC {- y -}) (WeakC VarC {- x -}))))
```

Note how `VarC` is the "variable bound by the last lambda", the one with De Bruijn index zero. If we want to access other variables we need to use `WeakC`.

Also note how application conveniently requires the same `n` on both sides -- not a loss of generalization, since we have weakening and we can make those indices to be the same `n` as needed.

Now, converting *closed* `Lam` terms to `LamC 'O` looks doable. I skipped this part, leaving it as an exercise. It might require one to use some `Nat` singletons and existentials, since this needs to be generalized to `... -> Maybe (exists n . (SNat n, LamC n))` to make it inductive. It looks like one needs to perform weakening in applications. Still, you should be able to actually code this.

```
-- Check if the term is closed, and in that case convert it
-- to LamC 'O. Return Nothing if the term is not closed.
lamToLamC :: Lam -> Maybe (LamC 'O)
lamToLamC _ = error "TODO"
```

Finally, the PHOAS terms:

```
data LamP p
   = VarP p
   | LamP (p -> LamP p)
   | AppP (LamP p) (LamP p)
```

Environments are now a GADT, providing values for exactly `n` variables. Essentially this is a sized list.

```
data Env (n :: Nat) p where
   Enil  :: Env 'O p
   Econs :: p -> Env n p -> Env ('S n) p
```

Now we can convert a `LamC` term to `LamP`, provided we have a suitable environment. This recurses just fine.

```
lamCToLamP :: Env n p -> LamC n -> LamP p
lamCToLamP (Econs _ rho ) (WeakC e)    =
   lamCToLamP rho e
lamCToLamP (Econs p _   ) VarC         =
   VarP p
lamCToLamP rho            (LamC e)     =
   LamP (\p -> lamCToLamP (Econs p rho) e)
lamCToLamP rho            (AppC e1 e2) =
   AppP (lamCToLamP rho e1) (lamCToLamP rho e2)
```

Note how here we do not have to return `Maybe (LamP p))`, which sidesteps the issue you found with `Nothing`s. Here we are sure that the environment provides a `p` and not a `Maybe p`, so everything is total (thanks to our GADTs) and we no longer need to worry.

Finally, we glue pieces together.

```
lamToLamP :: Lam -> Maybe (LamP p)
lamToLamP l = lamCToLamP Enil <$> lamToLamC l
```

Comment: Thanks, this technically answers my question. However, having to introduce an intermediate data type is not very satisfying to me. I would strongly prefer to be able to do it in a single pass.